# Jpa won't update row in database

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

Using Jpa with Eclipselink as my provider and Derby db.
I have a method that looks like this:

```
public void changeIndivid(long s,long id){
    et.begin();
    Individ C=em.find(Individ.class, id);
    System.out.println(C.s);
    C.s=s;
    System.out.println(C.s);
    em.flush();
    System.out.println(C.s);
    et.commit();
    System.out.println(C.s);
    em.merge(C);
    System.out.println(C.s);

}
```

and using some test data where the `s` column in each row has 1 then I call this method to change one of the rows so that the `s` column is 2. Here is the printout:

```
1
2
2
2
2
```

so apparently it works, but when I use SQuirreL to open the db all the rows have 1 in the `s` column.

ETA: I have tried both with and without either or both the flush() and merge(), and had merge before and after the commit, never throwing any exceptions or updating the row.

ETA2: here is the printout with logging level ALL (after removing "[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-03-29 15:03:40.077--UnitOfWork(1569403232)--Thread(Thread[Thread-2,5,main])" from all the lines that is from the logging):

```
--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="readIndivid" referenceClass=Individ sql="SELECT ID, S, TESTED, GENERATION_ID FROM INDIVID WHERE (ID = ?)")
1
2
--begin unit of work flush
--end unit of work flush
2
--begin unit of work commit
--end unit of work commit
--resume unit of work
2
--Merge clone with references nv3.nn.db.Individ@3b6c64f3
2
```

Comment: Putting a flush before commit is futile ... commit does a flush. Doing a merge needs a transaction yet that has none. Updating FIELDS of an entity is bad practice and should be through a setter so that a persistence process can intercept the change

Comment: I'll try changing to using getters and setters, but check out my edit.

Comment: PS That's what you have a LOG for.

Comment: no exceptions when I turned Logging level to all. Neither with merge before or after commit.

Comment: Who mentioned exceptions? It is a process called debugging. The log ought to tell you ample about what is going on, and if your changes are detected (and in the JPA implementation I use, any debug is simple because the log includes key info)

Comment: When are you checking the database values?  Check your database and connection settings, as an isolation setting might be preventing you from seeing the newly committed data in your SQuirreL connection/transaction.  As long as you can read the data in JPA after the app restarts, you should know its not a problem with JPA.